# Return selected rows as per Max value without duplicate using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

I am using MS SQL database. I need to selected rows as per Max value without duplicate. Tried SQL QUERY given below

```
Select  CId, 
        Rate,
        Max(FDateTime) 
from FTable 
Where OId = 1413 and type = 'C'
Group by CId,Rate
```

But it gives duplicate values.

I need Rate value and CID as per `MAX(FDateTime)`. How can I achieve this output?

I have tried Inner join concept also but I have faced some errors on that concept.

Comment: please post expected results and sample results as text and explain along with it

Comment: Should the query return a single row or all the rows where FDateTime = max(FDateTime)?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
  SELECT CID ,Rate ,FDateTime 
  FROM (SELECT   CID ,Rate ,FDateTime,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CID  ORDER BY FDateTime DESC) rank
         FROM FTable WHERE OId = 1413 and TYPE = 'C') AS T  WHERE rank=1
 ORDER BY CID
```

Comment: @NIKHILKA Can you attach a screenshot??

Comment: '106  6 2016-05-12 16:15:06.340
109  6 2016-07-28 15:33:06.247
109   6 2016-08-09 20:37:33.643
111  6 2016-08-08 21:23:00.487
106  7 2016-05-18 12:50:35.210'

Comment: @NIKHILKA  Which is the duplicate value in this?

Comment: First column CID,please check first and last record,i need only one record for that CID as per max Date

Comment: @NIKHILKA That's because both are having different rates. I guess you need the max rate. I have updated the my answer,check it.

Comment: Not max Rate.I need max(date) that means last updated date and it's corresponding rate and cid

Comment: @NIKHILKA For max date there's 2 records with different rates. In that case what should be displayed??

Comment: Latest date record

Comment: It should not b same because 'FDateTime' it's DateTime type Just consider two records. Order of columns are [CID,RATE,FDateTime] values are [001,6,2016-05-12 16:15:06.340],[001,7,2016-05-11 16:15:06.340].Both records CID is same but RATE,FDateTime are different.So I need latest 'FDateTime' records  Rate.NOTE:CID is not primary key for this table

Comment: @NIKHILKA, then you can mark it as the correct answer and give an upvote so that it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select ft.*
from (Select ft.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cid, rate order by fdatetime desc) as seqnum
      from FTable ft
      where ft.OId = 1413 and ft.type = 'C'
     ) ft
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you should be using a window function (if your Sql-Server version allow it) :

```
WITH TMP AS (
 SELECT CId, Rate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CId, Rate ORDER BY FDateTeim DESC) AS RNK
 FROM my_table
 WHERE .... )
SELECT CId, Rate
FROM TMP
WHERE RNK = 1
```

[MSDN ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this one,but still getting duplicate records

Comment: I would be really interested to see that. row_number guaranti you the uniqueness over the partition clause. So for the case asked it cannot return a duplicated line. Now if if you still think that you have some duplicated record then post the data in and the data out wanted with the structure of the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY to get `MAX(FDateTime)` for particular `OId` and `[type]`:

```
;WITH FTable AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(106, 6, '2016-05-12 16:15:06.340','C',1413),
(109, 6, '2016-07-28 15:33:06.247','C',1413),
(109, 6, '2016-08-09 20:37:33.643','C',1413),
(111, 6, '2016-08-08 21:23:00.487','C',1413),
(106, 7, '2016-05-18 12:50:35.210','C',1433)
) as t(CId,Rate,FDateTime,[type],OId)
)


SELECT  f.CId, 
        f.Rate,
        f.FDateTime
FROM FTable f
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(FDateTime) fdate
    FROM FTable 
    WHERE OId = f.OID and [type] = f.[type]
    ) as t
WHERE f.OId = 1413 and f.[type] = 'C' and t.fdate=f.FDateTime
```

Output:

```
CId Rate    FDateTime
109 6       2016-08-09 20:37:33.643
```

Comment: Yes,sorry for late reply.But I got this error "Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side."

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? I create temp table with samples like `(1,1,'2016-01-01,1413,'C') as (CId,Rate,FDateTime,[type],OId)` etc with various dates and all worked fine.

Comment: I add some sample data and output

Answer (score 0):

All Rate and CID for MAX(FDateTime) among OId = 1413 and type = 'C'

```
select  CId, 
        Rate,
        FDateTime 
from FTable f
where OId = 1413 and type = 'C'
  and FDateTime = (select Max(f2.FDateTime)
                   from FTable f2             
                   where f2.OId=f.Oid and f2.type = f.type)
```

Comment: it return only one record, I need all cid's latest FDateTime  records